# Fire base cloud function Typescript get value from fire base real time database On Updated

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

1. How to get the updated value of the node "Name" when
   "PostApproved"updated to true?
2. I read the firebase doc here, it can't help much. Is anyone know where to find tutorial about Firebase cloud function Typescript for firebase real time database?

   ```
   export const onPostApprovedUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Qpon/{country}/{city}/{nodeID}/PostApproved').onUpdate((change, context) => {

       const getCountry = context.params.country
       const getCity = context.params.city
       const getNode = context.params.nodeID

       const y = change.after.val()

       if (y == "true") {

       }

       return null
      });
   ```

[image]

Update:
[image]

it suppose to change the value of companyName to the data of the database , but it print out the value of companyName and companyKey are "XXX"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you trigger a Cloud Function from the realtime database, you get snapshots of the data at the point where you triggered. Since you trigger on `/Qpon/{country}/{city}/{nodeID}/PostApproved`, you only get the value of `PostApproved`.

To also get the value of the `Name` property, you have two options:

1. Load the additional data from the database in a separate call.
2. Trigger one level higher in the database: `/Qpon/{country}/{city}/{nodeID}`.

#### Trigger one level higher in the database

By triggering on `/Qpon/{country}/{city}/{nodeID}` you get all data that you need straight in the `change` parameter. A problem is that `onUpdate` will then also fire on changes to other properties, so you will need to check if that property was actually changed:

```
export const onPostApprovedUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Qpon/{country}/{city}/{nodeID}').onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const getCountry = context.params.country
    const getCity = context.params.city
    const getNode = context.params.nodeID

    const before = change.before.child("PostApproved").val()
    const y = change.after.child("PostApproved").val()

    if (before !== y && y == "true") {
        let name = change.after.child("Name").val();
        ...
    }

    return null
});
```

#### Load the additional data from the database in a separate call

To load the additional data in a separate call, you can get the `ref.parent` from the snapshot and use that to trigger an additional load. This of course requires an extra roundtrip, but will end up downloading less data:

```
export const onPostApprovedUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Qpon/{country}/{city}/{nodeID}/PostApproved').onUpdate((change, context) => {

    const getCountry = context.params.country
    const getCity = context.params.city
    const getNode = context.params.nodeID

    const y = change.after.val()
    if (y == "true") {
        const parentRef = change.after.ref.parent;
        return parentRef.child("Name").once("value").then((nameSnapshot) {
            let name = nameSnapshot.val();
            ...

        });
    }
    else {
        return null
    }
});
```

Comment: The values of `companyName` and `companyKey` will only be set **inside** of the callback function. Any code that requires these values must be inside the callback too.